# MVVM WPF BackgroundWorker and UI update

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm

i'm learning MVVM pattern with wpf and i'm trying to create a simple splashscreen for loading applications.

I have a simple class called Loading with two property which are bounded to my interface.

```
public class Loading : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Define current status value from 0 to 100.
    /// </summary>
    private int _currentStatus;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Define current status text.
    /// </summary>
    private string _textStatus;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Define constructor.
    /// </summary>
    public Loading(int status, string statusText)
    {
        _currentStatus = status;
        _textStatus = statusText;
    }

    public int CurrentStatus
    {
        get { return _currentStatus; }
        set
        {
            _currentStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CurrentStatus");
        }
    }

    public string TextStatus
    {
        get { return _textStatus; }

        set
        {
            _textStatus = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextStatus");
        }
    }

    #region Interfaces

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

From my ctor ViewModel i instanciate this model

```
Loading = new Loading(0, "Loading...");
```

and run a new thread calling the function GetSystemInfo() which perform some stuff in order to load some information.

```
Thread systemInfo = new Thread(GetSystemInfo);
systemInfo.IsBackground = true;
systemInfo.Start();
```

I'm updating the ui from GetSystemInfo() with

```
Loading.TextStatus = "Loading User Information...";
Loading.CurrentStatus = 50;
```

So far so good.. the thread is correctly updating the ui but the problem is that i wish to close this splashcreen and open a new window when the loading is complete but i'm unable to check if the thread is complete or at least i don't found a way to do that.

Is there any way i can solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You achieve this rather easily by using the [`Task`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) class (via [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)) with a combination of [`async-await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

What happens when you `await` on a `Task` is that the control is yielded back to the caller. In your case, the caller comes from the UI thread, so the control will return to the UI message loop, keeping you app responsive. Once the thread finishes it's work, it will return to the next line after the `await`, where you can then open the splash screen.

It will look like this:

```
public async void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => GetSystemInfo());
    // Here, you're back on the UI thread. 
    // You can open a splash screen.
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much i spent a lot of hours trying to solve this and the solution was really simple :D